Elasticsearch function score calculation
I'm working on an online shop and facing a challenge with sorting products in Elasticsearch. Here’s the scenario:
Each product can have multiple dynamic properties (e.g., category, color, neckline, occasion, style), and for each property, there are associated scores (ranging from 0 to 1) indicating the relevance of that property to the product. For example, a product might be:

Dress with a score of 1.0
Summer Dress with a score of 0.75
Black with a score of 0.8
Dark Blue with a score of 0.2

A product can have multiple values within each property group (e.g., two categories, three colors).
Problem:
I want to implement sorting logic using Elasticsearch's function_score to prioritize products with higher combined scores for selected filters. For instance, if the filters are set to Category: Dress and Color: Black/Red (multi-select), I want products with a higher combined score for Dress + Black/Red to appear at the top.
Currently, I can filter to get products that match the filters (e.g., Dresses that are Black/Red), but the sorting isn't ideal. Products with low scores for these filters can appear higher in the results, while others with higher combined scores are ranked lower.
I've used script_score to solve this, but the solution is too slow due to the size of the data. The dataset includes over 40,000 properties, and products dynamically change properties, so the mappings can become very large, making precomputing all combinations impractical.
Question:
How can I optimize this sorting logic in Elasticsearch without relying heavily on script_score due to its performance limitations? Are there alternative approaches that can efficiently handle large datasets with dynamic, multi-select filters?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

The key to solve this issue is property data organization. Property could be a nested document with 3 fields: type of property, value, and score
Mapping
PUT /products_with_properties
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "properties": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "score": {
                        "type": "double"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Documents
PUT /products_with_properties/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"properties":[{"type":"Category","value":"Dress","score":1},{"type":"Color","value":"Black","score":0.8}]}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"properties":[{"type":"Category","value":"Summer Dress","score":0.75},{"type":"Color","value":"Dark Blue","score":0.2}]}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"properties":[{"type":"Category","value":"Summer Dress","score":0.75},{"type":"Color","value":"Black","score":0.8}]}

Then query is a nested function_score with score by the sum of the properties.score fields
GET /products_with_properties/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "properties",
                    "query": {
                        "function_score": {
                            "query": {
                                "match_all": {}
                            },
                            "functions": [
                                {
                                    "field_value_factor": {
                                        "field": "properties.score",
                                        "missing": 0.1
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "params['_source']['properties'].size()"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Response, of course
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "products_with_properties",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 1.8,
                "_source" : {
                    "properties" : [
                        {
                            "type" : "Category",
                            "value" : "Dress",
                            "score" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "type" : "Color",
                            "value" : "Black",
                            "score" : 0.8
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "products_with_properties",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : 1.55,
                "_source" : {
                    "properties" : [
                        {
                            "type" : "Category",
                            "value" : "Summer Dress",
                            "score" : 0.75
                        },
                        {
                            "type" : "Color",
                            "value" : "Black",
                            "score" : 0.8
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "products_with_properties",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 0.95,
                "_source" : {
                    "properties" : [
                        {
                            "type" : "Category",
                            "value" : "Summer Dress",
                            "score" : 0.75
                        },
                        {
                            "type" : "Color",
                            "value" : "Dark Blue",
                            "score" : 0.2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

